# Building a map with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm writing a program that imports a map of symbols and recursively navigates the map. It's finished and it nearly works, but for whatever reason the map always skips one spot, and I can't find why. It's supposed to mark the correct path with 'X's and the parts not being used with a '+'. If anyone could check this out and find an error I missed, it would be greatly appreciated!

The grid I'm trying to traverse
looks like this:
[image]

When you run the code with the grid it also leaves some characters unchanged, and no matter where I put code it completely ignores it. I've tried putting something in like:

```
for i in grid:
    for j in i:
        if j == "|":
            j = "+"
        if j == "#":
            j = "+"
```

And the code I'm running it on is:

```
grid = []

def buildGrid ():
    with open("Maze.txt" , "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            chars = []
            for c in line:
                if c != "\n":
                    chars.append(c)
            grid.append(chars)    
    freeMouse(0, 0)

def showPath ():
    result = ""
    for i in grid:
        for j in i:
            result += " "
            result += j
        result += "\n"
    print(result)

def freeMouse (x, y):
    if grid[y][x] == "O":
        grid[0][0] = "S"
        showPath()
    elif grid[y][x] == "X":
        return False
    elif grid[y][x] == ("|"):
        grid[y][x]= "+"
        return False
    elif grid[y][x] == ("+"):
        return False
        print("false")
    grid[y][x] = "X"
    if x != 0:
        if y != 0:
            left = freeMouse (x-1, y)
            up = freeMouse(x, y -1)
            if len(grid) == y + 1:
                if len(grid[y]) != x+1:
                    right = freeMouse (x + 1, y)
                    if not right:
                        grid[y][x+1] = "+"
            else:
                if len(grid[y]) == x+1:
                    down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
                else:
                    down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
                    right = freeMouse (x + 1, y)
                    if not right:
                        grid[y][x+1] = "+"
                if not down:
                    grid[y+1][x] = "+"
            if not up:
                grid[y-1][x] = "+"
            if not left:
                grid[y][x-1] = "+"
        else:
            if len(grid[y])== x + 1:
                left = freeMouse (x-1, y)
                down = freeMouse (x, y+1)
            else:
                left = freeMouse (x-1, y)
                down = freeMouse (x, y+1)
                right = freeMouse (x+1, y)
                if not right:
                    grid[y][x+1] = "+"
            if not down:
                grid[y+1][x] = "+"
            if not left:
                grid[y][x-1] = "+"
    else:
        if y != 0:
            if len(grid) == y + 1:
                up = freeMouse(x,y-1)
                right = freeMouse (x+1, y)
            else:
                up = freeMouse(x, y-1)
                down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
                right = freeMouse(x + 1, y)
                if not down:
                    grid[y+1][x] = "+"
            if not up:
                grid[y-1][x] = "+"    
        else:
            down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
            right = freeMouse(x+1, y)
            if not down:
                grid[y+1][x] = "+"


buildGrid()
```

Comment: Please provide the input file you are using, so that the problem is reproducible. Also, post the result that you are getting.

Comment: Your code has lots of problems.  The function `freeMouse` never returns `True`; the only return values are `False` and `None`.  You have a print statement after a return statement, which is unreachable.  You call freeMouse several times in a row without checking the return value, which means that your program could continue to look for paths through the maze after it has already found one.  The first code snippet you give doesn't do anything since you modify the loop variables, not the grid.  If you think the code is "almost working" you are mistaken.

Comment: I'd suggest you first define/refactor parts of your code in conceptually atomic functions, then test each function independently before putting them together. That will give you a way to work it out step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and got the following output

```
 S X + + X X X X X X
 X + + X + X + + + X
 + X + + + X | # + X
 + X X X X X # # + X
 + + + + + | | | + X
 + + | + X X X X + X
 + + + X X | + X X X
 + + + X X # | + + +
 + + + + X + + X X X
 + + + + X X X X + O
```

I see a couple of spare #s that weren't processed.
I feel like the problem is in the return statements -- you should keep in mind that 'not None == True'
You can test this by opening a python console and typing the following

```
def func():
    return
print not func(); // This returns true
```

Thus, I would recommend removing the 'if not up', 'if not down', etc. statements.

```
if grid[y][x] == "O":
    grid[0][0] = "S"
    showPath()
# To stop from endless recursion -- don't go back to traversed path
elif grid[y][x] == "X":
    return False
# Don't run into wall
elif grid[y][x] == ("|"):
    grid[y][x]= "+"
    return False
# Don't run into locations already not traversable
elif grid[y][x] == ("+"):
    grid[y][x]= "+"
    return False
    print("false")
# Mark path as traversed
grid[y][x] = "X"

# If not at left end -- to avoid boundary issues
if x != 0:
    # If not at top end
    if y != 0:
        left = freeMouse (x-1, y)
        up = freeMouse(x, y -1)

        # If at bottom end
        if len(grid) == y + 1:
            # If not at right end -- traverse right
            if len(grid[y]) != x+1:
                right = freeMouse (x + 1, y)

        # If not at bottom end
        else:
            # If at right end -- traverse down
            if len(grid[y]) == x+1:
                down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
            # If not at right end -- traverse down or right
            else:
                down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
                right = freeMouse (x + 1, y)
    # If you are at top end
    else:
        # If you are at right end
        if len(grid[y])== x + 1:
            # Traverse left or down
            left = freeMouse (x-1, y)
            down = freeMouse (x, y+1)
        else:
            # Traverse left, down, or right
            left = freeMouse (x-1, y)
            down = freeMouse (x, y+1)
            right = freeMouse (x+1, y)
# If you are at left end
else:
    # If you aren't at top end
    if y != 0:
        # If you are at right end
        if len(grid) == y + 1:
            # Try to traverse right or up
            up = freeMouse(x,y-1)
            right = freeMouse (x+1, y)
        else:
            # Try to traverse up, down, right
            up = freeMouse(x, y-1)
            down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
            right = freeMouse(x + 1, y)
    # If you are at top end
    else:
        # Try to traverse down or right
        down = freeMouse(x, y+1)
        right = freeMouse(x+1, y)
```

If the requirement is simply to navigate from start to end though, I feel like you could simplify your code greatly

```
def freeMouse (x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or y+1 > len(grid)  or x+1 > len(grid[y]):
        return
    if grid[y][x] == "O":
        grid[0][0] = "S"
        showPath()
    elif grid[y][x] == "X":
        return 
    elif grid[y][x] == ("|"):
        grid[y][x]= "+"
        return
    elif grid[y][x] == ("+"):
        return

    grid[y][x] = "X"
    freeMouse(x-1,y)
    freeMouse(x+1,y)
    freeMouse(x,y-1)
    freeMouse(x,y+1)

    return
```

But then again, I'm not so sure of your requirements.
Let me know if the solution above doesn't work for you